# How to wait for function to finish and update tableview before segue. iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am making an e-commerce app. On the basket view controller, when the user taps on the Checkout button, I'd like to check the availability of the items and update the basket accordingly when for example the stock is not enough, the quantity will be changed to available stock, or the product is removed from the basket when there's no stock available before segueing to another view controller. The problem is, I have a function that has a completion handler that is supposed to call the performSegue only when the function is finished and if there are no changes to the basket, however, it still goes to another view controller before the function is finished. Any advice on how to properly do this?

Comment: Apparently `performSegue` is at the wrong place.

Comment: Show your code so we can help you

Comment: Try posting some minimal code to reproduce the issue. This would get you more accurate and quick answers.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your response. I think my completion handler was not correctly done that is why it didn't work. I was stuck for couple of hours but I finally got it to work just now.

Comment: if you don't think your question can be edited into a question easy for others to understand then you can just delete it

Answer (score 0):

My completion handler was not done correctly that is why it was not working. But I finally got it to work with the following code

```
    var changes = Bool()

    func getBasketItems(completion: @escaping(_ success:Bool) -> Void) {

     //each time there's an update to the database I set changes to true

    changes = true
    completion(changes)

    }
```

I use it as the code below

```
 self.getBasketItems { (success) in
     if success {
           // there are changes, update basket tableview
           print("there are changes")

        } else {

           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)

        }
      }
```